# Angular 2 Facebook Account Kit (ng2-account-kit ) initialization error

Tags: angular, account-kit

I am using "**ng2-account-kit**" library for login in an angular 4 app. I have initialized SDK in my login component like this :

```
ngOnInit() {
    AccountKit.init({
      appId: '{{FACEBOOK_APP_ID}}',
      state: '{{csrf}}',
      version: '{{ACCOUNT_KIT_API_VERSION}}'
    })
  }
```

Also I added this :
`<script src="https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_US/sdk.js"></script>`
in my index.html file.

I am getting "**AccountKit SDK was not initialized. Call AccountKit.init first." error**.  But when i reload the same page, it works properly.

I also tried initializing account kit on my app.component.ts file but got the same error.

Can anyone please tell what I am missing or where to properly initialize the account-kit?

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue. I added the following script in the **index.html**.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
         AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
         AccountKit.init(
          {
            appId:"myAppId",
            state:"{{csrf}}",
            version:"myAccountKitApiVersion",
            fbAppEventsEnabled:true,
            debug:true
         }
      );
    };
```

myAppId and myAccountKitApiVersion can be created by using the help of the following video. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2-PCiiJzr4